# What WOPI API needs to be implemented in order to support body.insertOoxml OfficeJs API call

Tags: office-js, ms-wopi, office-online-server

I am developing a Word Online add-in that is supposed to operate in an environment with a custom WOPI host.
We faced issues with a certain Office JS API which appears not to be supported on the WOPI host side. But we are struggling with identifying what exactly is missing.

Could anyone please help me to figure out what WOPI API needs to be implemented in order to support [insertOoxml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.body?view=word-js-preview#insertOoxml_ooxml__insertLocationString_) OfficeJs API call with `insertLocation` set to "Replace"?

What the sequence of calls to the WOPI host would be in this case?

The code is pretty simple and works as expected with SharePoint as a WOPI Host.

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
   var body = context.document.body;
   body.insertOoxml(ooxmlDoc, "Replace");
   return context.sync().then(function () {
   q.resolve();
 });
})
```

[image: RichApi.Error screenshot]

Unfortunately, I have very limited access to the WOPI host codebase to understand the root cause.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide code samples or links to your code with examples of your "insertOoxml" OfficeJS API implementation attempts. Without knowing exactly what you are trying to achieve, it's very difficult to answer your question.

Comment: I raised a bug report for this last year (https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/2893). No sign of a fix yet. My workaround was to use insertHtml(...) and then fix the formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

Can you fetch the [`CheckFileInfo`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html) of your WOPI host?

You need to make a GET request to `/wopi/files/(file_id)` with the right `access_token`. Then check the [WOPI Capabilities](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#wopi-host-capabilities-properties), especially things like:

- [`SupportsUpdate`](https://wopi.readthedocs.io/projects/wopirest/en/latest/files/CheckFileInfo.html#term-supportsupdate)